# How to convert/tag my video file so YouTube correctly identifies and displays it as 360 video

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, 360video

I have the following videofile (uploaded as is):

Which is a static timelapse of panorama photo's that spans a horizontal 360 degree field of view(and about a 40 degree vertical one), where the far left side of the frame would wrap to the far right side. I would like to convert/tag it to a proper 360 format to be recognized by YouTube and other applications.

I have tried importing it into Premiere Pro and creating a Equirectangular Monoscopic VR sequence and exporting it as a VR file which failed processing on Youtube after uploading. I have also tried passing it through ffmpeg first using the 360 filters, but I honestly don't know which format/projection I currently have(if any?) and what I should convert to.
[image: Error message in YouTube after processing]

How can I correctly convert my file, ideally using the tools I own/know (ffmpeg, Premiere Pro, Davinci Resolve)?